# Does the set operation define a binary operation on G?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the set G = {0,{1},{2},{1,2}}. Does the set operation intersection define a binary operation on G? Does the set operation union define a
binary operation on G? Is < G,(union) > a group? Explain. Is < G, (intersection) > a group?
Explain.

So I know that a binary operation takes all possible ordered pairs of elements of G and outputs an element of the set G. However, I do not understand how to apply this in this context... 
I also know that in order to be a group it is necessary that: 
the group is closed under a binary operation 
associative: (a*b)*c= a*(b*c)
identity: contains the identity element e
inverse: for every a in G, a^-1 is also in G

Comment: By $0$ do you mean the empty set?

Comment: Yes, 0 is the empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $(G,(\text{intersection}))$ be a group, $\varnothing=\varnothing\cap \{1\}=\varnothing \cap \{2\}$ implies $\{1\}=\{2\}$. contradiction.

In $(G,(\text{union}))$, $\varnothing$ is identity. associative law and commutative law are satisfied. but $\{1\}$ have not inverse i.e.
$$ \{1\}\cup A\ne \varnothing$$
for any $A\in G$.

Comment: But how do we know if the set operation union and intersection define a binary operation?

Comment: binary operator is just a function from $G\times G$ to $G$. $G$ is closed under union and intersection.

Comment: Yes, but could you please explain/show me why in this specific case?

Comment: $\varnothing=\varnothing\cap \{1\}=\varnothing\cap\{2\}=\varnothing\cap \{1,2\}, \{1\}\cap \{2\}=\varnothing, \{1\}\cap \{1,2\}=\{1\}, \{2\}\cap \{1,2\}=\{2\}$